# You can use interfaces to create const and nonconst versions of an interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I am currently reading Effective C# and found the following line very confusing:

> Last, but certainly not least, you can
>   use interfaces to create const and
>   nonconst versions of an interface:

What are and nonconst versions of an interface? And where would we use this?

Supporting code:

```
public interface IConstNameValuePair
{
  object Name
  {
    get;
  }

  object Value
  {
    get;
  }
}
public interface INameValuePair
{
  object Value
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

// Usage:
public class Stuff : IConstNameValuePair, INameValuePair
{
  private string _name;
  private object _value;

  #region IConstNameValuePair Members
  public object Name
  {
    get
    {
      return _name;
    }
  }

  object IConstNameValuePair.Value
  {
    get
    {
      return _value;
    }
  }

  #endregion

  #region INameValuePair Members

  public object Value
  {
    get
    {
      return _value;
    }
    set
    {
     _value = value;
    }
  }
  #endregion
}
```

Comment: I suggest reading another book ;)

Comment: @Mehrdad I agree such a dumb question deserved this comment. I overlooked the code.

Comment: Actually, I think this is the book's fault. The wording is pretty confusing.

Comment: That's a rather pernicious technique, because the IConstNameValuePair is in fact anything but const.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is showing that, through one of those interfaces, you can't actually modify the value (the 'set' property isn't defined). It's a little dubious to call this 'const', as that is actually a keyword that has special meaning. But that's what the author means.

Answer (score 1):

> What are and nonconst versions of an interface?

I think he means 'const' and 'non-const' in the way that a C++ programmer would understand them, i.e. as follows.

A 'const' interface is an interface whose properties you can't alter. For example in the following code, the test1 method can get but cannot set the properties of the stuff instance.

A 'non-const' interface is an interface whose properties you can alter, for example the test2 method can set as well as get the properties of the stuff instance.

```
void test()
{
  Stuff stuff = new Stuff();
  test1(stuff);
  test2(stuff);
}

void test1(IConstNameValuePair stuff)
{
}

void test2(INameValuePair stuff)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be clear that the choice of names used (const and nonconst) is very poor. Const typically refers to the idea that a value is **const**ant, meaning it cannot be changed.

Looking at the two interfaces, the `IConstNameValuePair` defines only a get property accessor. When you have an instance of `Stuff` that has been cast to an `IConstNameValuePair` then you effectively have an unchangeable instance because through the interface there is no way to change the values.

The `INameValuePair` interface defines both a get and a set property accessor. When you have an instance of `Stuff` that has been cast to an `INameValuePair` then you effectively have a changeable instance because through the interface you can change the values.

That being said, there are certainly better approaches to solve this problem than using two different interfaces.